# i want to reset the game in spark ar blinking game when it finishes

Tags: apache-spark, spark-ar-studio

I have created a simple blinking game, after resetting the game, I'm unable to reset the "faster option" for the loop for background.
I want after the reset button is pressed the game to go back to the initial stage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

he wants to reload the scene/game, restart the filter, reset.
for which spark ar dosenot provide basic functionality.